# Will webworkers continue to run when the phone is locked in browsers

Tags: javascript, html

I have tried to use the webworker to run in background ,but when the phone is in locked state the webworker is not running.

Comment: Ok... can you expand on your question?

Comment: so you already know the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

the webworker will only work as long as the phone's browser is running. Locking the phone stops your browser app and with it your webworker. it's the same as closing the website where the webworker is running in.